# Do I use timeslot or time slot or time-slot?

Tags: hyphenation, spacing

As in *"the timeslot given to completing the task"*.  Would also be interested to hear if there's different usages for different scenarios.

Comment: Probably the most familiar for your use is *in the time allotted*. A time slot is a slot in a schedule: *...shows such as Jeopardy! were popular in the time slot.*

Comment: This is a very clear case where research material is easily obtained and should be shown.

Comment: I just searched for this, only to find I'd already upvoted one of the answers. This question has helped me twice now. "time slot".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/time+slot), it should be two separate words "**time slot**".

[This useful article](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/042703compwdshyph.htm) on compound words offers the following advice:

> Many of them are found in the dictionary and are not subject to our
>   interpretation, our judgment, or our whim. Start with your dictionary
>   before applying any other guidelines.

I would be inclined to follow that advice, and use the dictionary version: **time slot**.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that *time slot* is currently most common, but that doesn’t prevent you from adhering to more (or less) traditional approaches.

Here is the [google n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=timeslot%2Ctime%20slot%2Ctime-slot&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctimeslot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20slot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20-%20slot%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctimeslot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20slot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20-%20slot%3B%2Cc0) of the variants in use since 1940.

[image: Google n-gram of word usage since 1940]

And it is always worth browsing at more venerable sources such as *The New Yorker*’s inimitable [Comma Queen](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/comma-queen-mad-dash), Mary Norris, or, indeed, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/timeslot).

Comment: You are correct. I believe I’ve been foiled once again by autocorrect. I’ll update it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both timeslot and time slot are acceptable. You will find an equal amount of dictionaries containing either.

Regarding the hyphenated version, there's been a general trend to move away from hyphenated compound words over the past 40 years. A common, historical pattern is that two words — say, time slot — will be joined by a hyphen for a time — time-slot — and then be joined into one word — timeslot. English is moving away from this and joining languages like German, where words are advantageously and immediately linked to one another.

Comment: *"You will find an equal amount of dictionaries containing either."* Is that so? Why don't you name them, so we can see for ourselves how many are in each group, and how reputable they are.